# Getting segmentation fault when trying to access a complex structure

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault when trying to print a string value from inside of a structure.
I am trying to access cdata parameter.

I am getting segmentation fault at the indicated line.

```
struct node_id{
    union {
         uint32_t numeric;
         struct my_string *string;
         struct my_bytestring *opaque;
    } identifier;
    enum my_identifiertype type;
    uint16_t index;
};

struct my_string{
    uint32_t len : 31;
    uint32_t free: 1;
    union {
      const char *cdata;
      char *data;
    } d;
};

get_nodeid(node_t node, struct nodeid *id){
   //some code
}

struct nodeid *id;
get_nodeid(node,id);
printf("%s", id->identifier.string->d.cdata );   // ------- Seg Fault comes here
nodeid_clear(&id);
```

If I print only id using format specifier %o(object),it does not give seg fault and while debugging it shows not able to access memory location for cdata.

Can someone help me understand,why is there segmentation fault while accessing it,when it has been used the same way in other parts of the code also.

Comment: `get_nodeid` expects a `struct nodeid *id`, but you pass `struct nodeid **id` (mind the `**`). Have you turned all compiler warnings on?

Comment: `string` is a pointer in the struct `node_id`. Have you allocated memory for this? Are you sure this pointer is not NULL.

Comment: `struct nodeid *id;` is an *Uninitialized Pointer*. `get_nodeid(node,&id);` likely invokes *Undefined Behavior*. Dereferencing `id` causes the SegFault.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `get_nodeid` was apparently meant to initialize `id`. The problem is that it does not.

Comment: Agreed, without seeing it, it's hard to tell. Passing the address of the pointer would allow allocation, but was it? Dunno... Further the declaration `get_nodeid(node_t node, struct nodeid *id)` does not match the call `get_nodeid(node,&id);`

Comment: Edited the call

Comment: OK, now it definitely will not work. Any changes made to `id` in `get_nodeid` will not be seen back in `main()`. Why? C is pass-by-value, so `get_nodeid` receives *a-copy-of* the pointer `id`. Any changes made to `id` in `get_nodeid` are lost on function return. You can change the `get_nodeid` declaration to `get_nodeid(node_t node, struct nodeid **id)` and pass `&id` as a parameter to insure the function receives the actual *address-of* the pointer which you can then allocate for and have the allocation survive return.

Comment: Meaning after making the changes above, then within `get_nodeid` you could allocate for a node with `*id = malloc (sizeof **id);` and then validate the allocation succeeded by checking `if (*id == NULL) { /* handle error */ }` and then use the actual pointer `*id` as needed to have the changes to `id` visible back in `main()` (or the calling function).

Comment: But this function declaration cannot be changed as it is a library function that i'm using.Any way i can change the calling mechanism to get the proper value?

Comment: @user2156513 Then I think the function is expecting a pointer to an allocated chunk of type `struct nodeid`?. which is defined by... you? first time for me.